# Facebook API - 63 Build Errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

i'm new by working with the Facebook SDK.
First i want to build this tutorial: [TuT](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

After i add the SDK and Build i get 63 Errors from the Facebook SDK.
Here are Some:
[image: Errors]

I'm using XCODE 4.2 and iOS 5.
Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Any sample of your code, or haven't you got that far?

Comment: i have not written any code in the project, only import the sdk.

Comment: Check that you've installed everything correctly.  Once that's done I suggest reimporting the SDK.  I'm afraid apart from that I don't know the answer.  I'll +1 it for you!

Comment: i import and download it several times :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook SDK hasn't been adopted to support ARC yet. You can try disabling ARC for all files belonging to the Facebook SDK by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files (under Build Phases).

If that doesn't work you'll probably have to disable ARC for the entire project. To do that set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to NO (Under Build Settings / All). This is probably the easier way.

Comment: I can confirm, at least as far as logging in goes, that the -fno-objc-arc option works. Detailed instructions of how to do this (in general, not for this specific case) are here:
http://sugartin.info/2011/08/10/ios5-how-to-turn-off-arc-on-individual-files/